# Springboot cache vs hazelcast implementation

Tags: hazelcast, spring-cache

I have a doubt with springboot cache vs Hazelcast implementation.

In my scenario I want the cacheName say **logout** to **clear its entry every 60mins**, irrespective of size Policy/ Expiration policy.

For that i saw in HazelCast with manual entry

```
map.put(K key, V value, long ttl, TimeUnit timeunit)
```

I want to know is there any customization position with springboot-cache annotation/ config manupulation only for this cache name and can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I need to write that you ask for a technical solution, but you don't mention your use-case. I'm afraid answering your question might do more harm than good.

Now, Spring Boot has no cache *per se* but relies on implementation. Hazelcast is one of them. Since the feature you mention is not common across all implementations, there's no option to configure it.

If you want to clear the cache regardless of TTL, you should add a `@Scheduled` bean that does it according to your frequency. Since the [available tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) is quite complete, I don't find the need to copy-paste it here.